# Pass PictureBox Object to Method in Class

Tags: c#, parsing, object, methods, picturebox

I am trying to find information in regards to passing a picturebox to a method, I tried passing it with object, but to no avail.

Could someone point me into the right direction to research the answer myself, i have tried many searches but im not sure on the correct wording to use when looking for such a answer.

I am creating a class that manipulates the picture box that was passed to it.

```
public class picBoxStuff
{
    public void doStuff(Object pictureBox)
    {
        pictureBox.dooooostufff....
    }
}
```

Thanks kindly in advance,

EDIT:

Thanks guys, Unfortuanlty i cant vote you both as answers but you both where fantastic,
Ill add a note here to add to what you both mentioned for people searching for this in the future.

First add a reference to system.windows.forms, by you will find it in .net references.
Next add the usage line "usage System.Windows.Forms;".
And finally you can pass the pictureBox as a picturebox to a method.

A bit silly of me to forget to add the refrence fo windows.forms :)

Thanks again guys,
Scott

Answer (score 4, accepted):

PictureBox is an object because all classes inherit from that class but you should treat it like a PictureBox instead of Object. So the method should require a PictureBox object instead than an Object 'object' as the parameter being pass to the method.

```
using System;
using System.Drawing;
using System.Windows.Forms;

namespace WindowsFormsApplication5
{
    public partial class Form1 : Form
    {
        public Form1()
        {
            InitializeComponent();
        }

        private void button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            someMethod(pictureBox1);
        }

        private void someMethod(PictureBox p)
        {
            p.BackColor = Color.Blue;
            // this is an example of pictureBox being passed as 
            // a paramter to this method
        }
    }
}
```

[image]

Comment: hmm i thought that was the case but when i try to do that it does not regester that PictureBox is something.

Comment: Then that is because the PictureBox that you are trying to pass is not instantiated (null). Are you creating the PictureBox with code? I If you drag the control to your form it should work. Just like the example that I showed you.

Answer (score 1):

what if you do this?

```
using System.Windows.Forms;

//rest of your code
```

Comment: thanks mate, using your answer and the one above was perfect, i more thing to add for noobs you have to make reference to "system.Windows?Forms" first before you add the using line.